# Under what conditions can we use change of variables in an integral with respect to the Hausdorff measure?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let ${\cal H}^m$ be the $m$-dimensional Hausdorff measure, $A$ be a ${\cal H}^m$-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($m<n$), and $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be an injective Lipschitz function.
Under what conditions is it true that

$$
\int_{f(A)}gd{\cal H}^m=\int_{A}g\circ fJfd{\cal H}^m
$$

for some function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $Jf$ is the Jacobian of $f$?

I know from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107443/change-of-variable-within-an-integral-of-the-hausdorff-measure) that this does not hold in general, but is there any set of conditions under which this holds?

Comment: You can find something similar in Theorem 3.2.22 in Federer.

Comment: @UmbertoP.Thanks! I looked at the theorem, and this is very helpful.